# hibernate - error during frequent queries

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I use server Tomcat + HttpServlet + hibernate. I test the server performance, for this, I created an application that simulates the operation 500 clients, each client with a periodicity repeats HTTP requests to the server.

**when requests connection = 900 (+-100) i start getting hibernate errors**

```
24.04.2013 12:27:20 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08001
24.04.2013 12:27:23 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:304)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler.extractPhysicalConnection(ConnectionProxyHandler.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler.continueInvocation(ConnectionProxyHandler.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
    at $Proxy24.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:166)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1711)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:828)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:289)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2438)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2424)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2254)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2249)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:470)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:355)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1248)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractQueryImpl.uniqueResult(AbstractQueryImpl.java:890)
    at actions.player.LoginAction.perform(LoginAction.java:20)
    at action.Action.performAction(Action.java:66)
    at servlets.RequestHandlerServlet.service(RequestHandlerServlet.java:34)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException:
org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:136)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:64)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:123)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:28)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:20)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:30)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:22)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:391)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:265)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:281)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:297)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:60)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:74)
    ... 54 more
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:304)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler.extractPhysicalConnection(ConnectionProxyHandler.java:82)
```

please help, any ideas ...

Comment: So you've found the load limit of your application. Wasn't that the point?

Comment: @Marko Topolnik I think this is not the limit. My CPU and RAM is not fully loaded

Comment: You just made the wrong assumption that your application would be CPU/RAM-limited. It is actually I/O-limited (more specifically, you run out of database connections), which is the usual case for most business applications.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik How can I raise the I/O-limited? in this case

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Running out of database connections has different symptoms to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specific problem is:

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

This shows that when PgJDBC attempted to open a TCP/IP socket to the PostgreSQL server the connection was rejected.

This doesn't happen when the PostgreSQL server is overloaded; it'll instead accept the connection for long enough to reply with an error mentioning "too many connections" or "`max_connections`". When I tested with `psql` against Pg 9.3-HEAD I got:

```
FATAL:  sorry, too many clients already
```

Similarly, if authentication is a problem, PostgreSQL will accept the connection, reply with an error message, and close the connection, like:

```
FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "[local]", user "craig", database "postgres"
```

or:

```
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "craig"
```

What you are seeing is a lower level issue in your OS or networking stack. It's happening before PostgreSQL gets a chance to accept the connection. Since you have not mentioned your operating system, whether the Pg server is local or remote to the app server, or pretty much anything else it's hard to help further with that. I'd start by:

- Checking the PostgreSQL logs for errors about `accept()` or anything else unusual-looking
- Investigating any TCP/IP connection limits and max open file limits in the operating system
- Making sure I wasn't using any kind of dodgy 3rd party software firewall or "Internet security" suite

Furthermore, you should investigate using a connection pooler - either an in-app one, or an external pooler like PgPool-II, allowing you to reduce `max_connections` to an efficient level.  PostgreSQL will perform *better* with *fewer* connections; the ideal number depends on workload and hardware. See [PostgreSQL wiki: Number of database connections](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Number_Of_Database_Connections).

Comment: I'm a little closer to unraveling. When in TomCat config set <Connector maxThreads="5000" - I started getting error, but when maxThreads="1000" - no errors . I can not understand why this is happening

Comment: I'm testing the application on my PC (Windows)

Comment: @MaxUsanin Wow, ok... on a Windows PC you should be looking at `max_connections` somewhere between 20 and 50, with a corresponding connection limit in your app server a little lower than that. The application will perform *better* when it queues connections rather than trying to do too much all at once. Windows (non-server versions) has some pretty low limits on TCP/IP connections, open files, etc.

Comment: @CraigRinger Your answer looks more correct, I've removed mine.

Comment: *shrug*. Maybe post a new question that raises the `maxThreads` issue and provides appropriate details (http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql/info). I still suspect you're exceeding operating system resources.

Comment: Looked at the logs again I saw --  `24.04.2013 16:35:24 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: FATAL: sorry, too many clients already
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection`

Comment: maybe i used the more than 100 connections on Postgres